# Efficient algorithm to calculate the sum of all k-products

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose you are given a list `L` of `n` numbers and an integer `k<n`. Is there an efficient way to calculate the sum of all products of `k` distinct numbers in `L`?

As an example, take `L=[1,3,4,6]` and `k=2`. Then the number I am looking for is

`1*3 + 1*4 + 1*6 + 3*4 + 3*6 + 4*6`.

Can you think of a way of doing it which avoids generating all the subsets of size `k`?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid having all sets exist in memory at a certain point in time, or attempting to find a solution that bypasses the idea of enumerating the subsets altogether? A recursive solutions seems to be fine for the first requirement.

Comment: k is an integer smaller than the length of the list L.

Comment: I want to avoid enumeration. Imagine n=100 and k=50, then I'd have to generate something like 10^30 subsets (100 choose 50) which is not feasible.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was quick! (@PengOne, why did you tag my question as "homework"?) The two best answers are by Daniel Fischer (most elegant) and ElKamina (fastest)... I will accept the one which gets most votes by tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let F(X,k,n) be the k-product sum of first n elements of array X.

F(X,k,n) = F(X,k,n-1)+F(X,k-1,n-1)*X[n]

which you can solve using dynamic programming. Complexity = O(kn).

End conditions for F(X,k,n): When n=k F(X,k,k) = X[1]* X[2]*...*X[n]

More details:

```
F(X,1,1) = X[1]
F(X,1,i) = F(X,1,i-1)+X[i] for i=2...n 

For j=2..n:
    For i = 1..k:
        if i<j:
            F(X,i,j) = F(X,i,j-1)+F(X,i-1,j-1)*X[j]
        else if i==j:
            F(X,i,j) = F(X,i-1,j-1)*X[j]
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: that double for loop won't work, you have to fill in the matrix diagonally... right? but it's probably easier to write a memoizer solution.

Comment: @yi_H Thanks. It should be okay now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. Consider the polynomial

```
(X + a[0]) * (X + a[1]) * ... * (X + a[n-1])
```

Its coefficients are just the sums of the `k`-products, its degree is `n`, so you can calculate the sum of all `k`-products for all `k` simultaneously in O(n^2) steps.

After `s` steps, the coefficient of X<sup>s-k</sup> is the sum of the `k`-products of the first `s` array elements. The `k`-products of the first `s+1` elements fall into two classes, those involving the `(s+1)`<sup>st</sup> element - these have the form `a[s]*((k-1)`-product of the first `s` elements) - and those not involving it - these are the `k`-products of the first `s` elements.

Code such that `result[i]` is the coefficient of X<sup>i</sup> (the sum of the `(n-i)`-products):

```
int *k_products_1(int *a, int n){
    int *new, *old = calloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    int d, i;
    old[0] = 1;
    for(d = 1; d <= n; ++d){
        new = calloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
        new[0] = a[d-1]*old[0];
        for(i = 1; i <= d; ++i){
            new[i] = old[i-1] + a[d-1]*old[i];
        }
        free(old);
        old = new;
    }
    return old;
}
```

If you only want the sum of the `k`-products for one `k`, you can stop the calculation at index `n-k`, giving an O(n*(n-k)) algorithm - that's good if `k >= n/2`. To get an O(n*k) algorithm for `k <= n/2`, you have to organise the coefficient array the other way round, so that `result[k]` is the coefficient of X<sup>n-k</sup> (and stop the calculation at index `k` if you want only one sum):

```
int *k_products_2(int *a, int n){
    int *new, *old = calloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    int d, i;
    old[0] = 1;
    for(d = 1; d <= n; ++d){
        new = calloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
        new[0] = 1;
        for(i = 1; i <= d; ++i){
            new[i] = old[i] + a[d-1]*old[i-1];
        }
        free(old);
        old = new;
    }
    return old;
}
```

Comment: This answer is referring to the fact that you want to evaluate the [elementary symmetric polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) `e_k` at the values given by `L`.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting property you could explore is the distributive property of multiplication in relation to addition.

```
L=[a,b,c,d]
```

When k = 1, it's trivial:

```
S=a+b+c+d
```

When k = 2:

```
S = a * (b + c + d) + b * (c + d) + c * d
```

When k = 3, things get a bit more interesting:

```
S = a * b * ( c + d) + (c * d) * (a + b)
S = a * (b * (c + d)) + c * d) + b * (c * d)  <-- this form lends itself better to the algorithm
```

And for k = 4:

```
S = a * b * c * d
```

This should hold for larger values of n.

An implementation in C#:

```
 private static int ComputeSum(int[] array, int offset, int K)
 {
     int S = 0;

     if (K == 1)
     {                      
         for (int i = offset; i < array.Length; i++)
             S += array[i];
     }
     else if ((array.Length - offset) == K)
     {
         S = array[offset] * ComputeSum(array, offset + 1, K - 1);
     }
     else if (offset < array.Length)
     {
         S = ComputeSum(array, offset + 1, K) + array[offset] * ComputeSum(array, offset + 1, K - 1);             
     }

     return S;
 }
```

Which can be further improved by memoization.

Comment: You can make it even better if you write: `a*(b*(c+d)+c*d)+b*(c*d)`. This way, you make it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce k by 1:

e.g. for k=2

```
1*3 + 1*4 + 1*6 + 3*4 + 3*6 + 4*6
```

==

```
1*(3+4+6)+3*(4+6)+4*6
```

and for k=3

```
1*3*4 + 1*3*6 + 3*4*6
```

==

```
1*3*(4+6) + 3*4*6
```

So basically you cycle your list, then recurse to the same algorithm with k reduced by 1 and only the rest of the list

Answer (score 0):

For k=2,

let's `s = SUM_x_in_L x` (sum of the numbers) and `sq = SUM_x_in_L x^2` (sum of the squares)

then it's `SUM_x_in_L (s - x) * x / 2 = (s * s - sq) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically, for `k=2` just take the sum of the elements of `L`, square it, and subtract the sum of the squares of `L`. That is:

```
int sum = 0;
int sqSum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    sum += L[i];
    sqSum += L[i]*L[i];
}
return sum*sum - sqSum;
```

In your example, what you are computing is this

```
(1 + 3 + 4 + 6)^2 - (1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 6^2) = 1*3 + 1*4 + 1*6 + 3*4 + 3*6 + 4*6
```

This should give you a hint for how to proceed in general.

Comment: Not sure how you would extend this to a general k.

Comment: You need to divide by 2 since the mixed terms can be obtained two ways.