# Algorithm to maximize the sum of product(SOP) of elements of two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures

I've already posted the question. The link to the question is here:
[Algorithm to maximize the sum of product of elements of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40138318/7030159)
As I haven't received any answers. I'm taking your attention towards the question again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Please don't spam.

Comment: Do not repost a question. If you want to get attention to your old question, edit it to improve it, or, once you have enough reputation, you can put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Seems like you want to do something similar except instead of a k you have an another array of k's. I think you should be able to use this algorithm.

[Efficient algorithm to calculate the sum of all k-products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280936/efficient-algorithm-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-k-products)

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this (i.e. blatantly obvious duplicates). Instead, if your answer isn't already there, post your answer on the original question. In addition, please [edit] your answer so that if I were to totally delete all links -- say, by letting time pass until the links no longer point to the content you want to reference -- it would still answer the question.